# Telerik RadTimePicker always selecting morning hours

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have an issue with RadTimePicker, the users have the option to select an hour from 00:00 to 11:00, but whenever the user selects a time from 12:00 pm to 11:00 pm it shows the number properly but it changes to a.m.

[image: Example, the user select 10:00pm and converts it automatically to 10:00 am]

There is no error displayed on Chrome dev tools console or debugging, I have no idea what is going on. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the version of Telerik UI and it started working properly again. No a single change in the code.